# Convert file to iso-8859-1 (ok from utf-8 but fails on us-ascii files)

Tags: git, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I have a git repository, html, js, php files mostly encoded in UTF-8. All of them should be encoded in UTF-8 but executing `file -i *` shows most of them are UTF-8 but some of them like this:

> file.html.twig: text/plain; charset=us-ascii

Extrangely, if I open that files with Sublime text it shows UTF-8. And if I execute this conversion:

`iconv -f us-ascii -t iso-8859-1 file.html.twig -o file2.html.twig`

or

`iconv -f utf-8 -t iso-8859-1 file.html.twig -o file2.html.twig`

Nothing changes, while if I execute this command over an utf-8 file conversion is actually done.

Why does this happen? I know us-ascii is a subset of utf-8, but iconv seems unable to change this charset.

(My ultimate goal is to maintain a git repository with files in iso-8859-1, and git seems not to recognize file encoding, this will be a second problem, first I need to resolve this...)

thank you

Comment: Can you show a hex dump of a problematic character sequence?

Comment: The problem is with the file encoding itself, the content is ok, I need all my source code in ISO-8859-1 (I know it is not a wise solution but this code is co-living with a legacy disaster app and I have no chocice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are in UTF-8, then don't let a guesser like `file` mislead you. It gives one answer when it could give many; whenever it guesses ASCII, it could also include UTF-8, iso-8859-1 *and* dozens of others.

So, take all your UTF-8 files and convert them to iso-8859-1. But do understand that it could be a lossy conversion, so don't override iconv's default behavior telling you about that with an error.

Oh, but, you are converting files that might have internal declarations of their encodings (e.g., HTML and XML), you should have update their declarations.

And, if there are errors, you can usually change the content to a different representation of the characters not supported by iso-8859-1, according to whatever language ( => \uD83D\uDEB2 or similar) or markup rules ( => &#x1f6b2;) apply.

Comment: I don't understand this bit very well: *But do understand that it could be a lossy conversion, so don't override iconv's default behavior telling you about that with an error.* the rest I understand, and I will batch convert to iso-8859-1. Thank you

Comment: Did it, only had problems with euro symbol (€) even if I use iso-8859-15 which is supposed to have euro symbol, just replacing it with `&euro;` does the job

Comment: iconv 1.11 converts e2 82 ac to a4 as expected for me. As for errors, you could tell iconv to ignore some data loss by appending //IGNORE to the tocode but I have never wanted such behavior.